# Effects of 0 calorie drinks on weight loss

Tags: weight-loss, exercise, weight-gain

Is there any conclusive study or research on effects of 0 calorie drinks on weight loss?

As far as I know these drinks have nothing that the body can digest, so body doesn't store anything from these drinks which means 0 calorie. However I've read that long terms effects indicate that they are not affecting the body as if they are 0 calorie.

I drink 3L of Pepsi Max a week on average. While logging my intake, should I assume they are 0 calories? (Technically yes they are but I'm talking about practically)

Comment: [This article](http://www.scientificamerican.com/article/artificial-sweeteners-may-change-our-gut-bacteria-in-dangerous-ways/) might seem a bit tabloid-ish, but I can't seem to find a paper that's not paywalled. Anyway, it seems like there's reason to believe that 0 calorie drinks might actually not be that great :/

Comment: I'd argue that the only drink with real 0 calories *(without any hidden side effects/complications)* is water; all other drinks contain calories in minute quantities or worse, harmful chemicals that might be worse than consuming sugar.

Answer (score 3):

One study reflects that 0 calorie drinks may actually cause weight gain:

> “On average, for each diet soft drink our participants drank per day,
>   they were 65 percent more likely to become overweight during the next
>   seven to eight years, and 41 percent more likely to become obese,”
>   said Sharon Fowler, M.P.H., faculty associate in the division of
>   clinical epidemiology in the Health Science Center’s department of
>   medicine. She presented the finding June 12 in San Diego at the
>   American Diabetes Association’s 65th Annual Scientific Sessions.

More info:
http://uthscsa.edu/hscnews/singleformat2.asp?newID=1539

As for assuming they are 0 calories, every country has their own food labeling laws, but in the US anything lower than 4 is considered 0. So yes, technically there are around 0 calories, but as the study shows, there is more to it than that, and you might want to consider avoiding them.

More info on labeling laws in the US by the FDA:
http://www.fda.gov/Food/GuidanceRegulation/GuidanceDocumentsRegulatoryInformation/LabelingNutrition/ucm064911.htm

Comment: Thank you, so I guess there is no certain result.